# Powershell script delete remote backups in 2 folders failing

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete backups older than 30 days on a remote server. The backups sit in 2 folders and this is the script I am working on so far. Thank you for your help.

```
$remoteserver = '\\SFTP01\'
$rootFolder = 'D$\FTP_Root\backups\'
$folder = 'Backups1\','Backups2\'

    foreach($folders in $folder){
        $fullPath = ( $remoteserver + $rootFolder + $folder + '*.BKP*')
        Get-ChildItem –Path $fullPath *.BKP* -recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item -Recurse
    }
```

Comment: How’s it failing? What’s the errors? Have you looked into ``invoke-command``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is that you define an array `$folder` and you loop through this array `foreach($folders in $folder)` so the single element of the array is currently stored in the variable `$folders` but once you build the target path you provide the variable `$folder ($fullPath = ( $remoteserver + $rootFolder + $folder + '*.BKP*'))` which is the array and not the single element.

Furthermore you could pass an array to the parameter  `path` of the `get-childitem` cmdlet.

So you could do:

```
$remoteserver = '\\SFTP01\'
$rootFolder = 'D$\FTP_Root\backups\'
$folder = @('Backups1\','Backups2\')
$paths = @(
    $folder | %{
        $remoteserver + $rootFolder + $_
    }
)

Get-ChildItem –Path $paths -Filter '*.BKP*' -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item -Recurse
```